# How to change ActionBar color "Options"?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I change the color of an ActionBar "Options" menu?
I changed `backgroundcolor`:

```
<style name="AppActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just that the control is focused? E.g. if you had an edit text and hit down on the d-pad, it may turn white and the edit text may get focused and highlighted.